# Change print icon programmically through template.php

Tags: 7

I'm using the [Print module](https://www.drupal.org/project/print), version 7.2, and trying to change the icon through the template.php.

After researching, I have found the main [functionality](https://www.drupal.org/node/190173#themeicon) in the FAQ of the module, which provides this:

> The example below is for the 6.x-1.x and 7.x-1.x branches. In 7.x-2.x
> the theme function is theme_print_ui_format_link.
>
> You will have to define a theme_print_format_link function which will replace
> the module's function with the same name and where you can indicate your
> custom-defined icon, and set the html element to true so that your
> image tag is interpreted as HTML. See the following for an example:

```
function theme_print_format_link() {
  $print_html_link_class = variable_get('print_html_link_class', 'print-page');
  $print_html_new_window = variable_get('print_html_new_window', 0);
  $print_html_show_link = variable_get('print_html_show_link', 1);
  $print_html_link_text = filter_xss(variable_get('print_html_link_text', t('Printer-friendly version')));

  $img = local_path_to_your_img_file;
  $title = t('Display a printer-friendly version of this page.');
  $class = strip_tags($print_html_link_class);
  $new_window = $print_html_new_window;
  $format = _print_format_link_aux($print_html_show_link, $print_html_link_text, $img);

  return array('text' => $format['text'],
               'html' => $format['html'],
               'attributes' => print_fill_attributes($title, $class, $new_window),
              );
}
```

1. If I don't change the code at all, it never gets called.
2. If I change the first line to `subtheme_print_ui_format_link() {`, it gets called, but then I get the error

   `Fatal error: Call to undefined function _print_format_link_aux() in ...../public_html/sites/all/themes/subtheme/template.php on line ...`

I have tried:

- `subtheme_print_format_link_aux()`
- `_subtheme_print_format_link()`
- `_print_ui_format_link_aux()`
- `_print_ui_format_link()`

and a bunch of others instead of `_print_format_link_aux()`, but error just replaces the first function with the one I tried.

**Note:** I have have changed `local_path_to_your_img_file` to `'images/print_icon.png'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a site that helped me a lot. I just changed the `$icon` value.

This is the code I am using in the template file.

```php
/**
 * Format the Printer-friendly link
 *
 * @return array
 *   An associative array containing:
 *   - text: The content of the link
 *   - html: TRUE if the text contains HTML tags, FALSE if it's plain text
 *   - attributes: several attributes of the link tag (title, class, target,
 *     onclick, rel)
 *
 * @see _print_ui_fill_attributes()
 * @ingroup themeable
 * @ingroup print_themeable
 */
function subtheme_print_ui_format_link($vars) {
  $format = $vars['format'];
  $path = '/images/print_icon.png'; //path to file, relative to theme YOUR_THEME

  foreach (module_implements('print_link') as $module) {
    $function = $module . '_print_link';
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      $link = call_user_func_array($function, array());
      if ($link['format'] == $format) {
        $link_class = variable_get('print_' . $link['format'] . '_link_class', $link['class']);
        $new_window = FALSE;
        $func = $module . '_print_new_window_alter';
        if (function_exists($func)) {
          $func($new_window, $link['format']);
        }
        $show_link = variable_get('print_' . $link['format'] . '_show_link', PRINT_UI_SHOW_LINK_DEFAULT);
        $link_text = filter_xss(variable_get('print_' . $link['format'] . '_link_text', $link['text']));
        if ($show_link >= 2) {
          // Work out which icon we want to show based on the link's format.
          switch ($link['format']) {
            case 'html':
              $icon_name = 'print';
              break;  
            
            case 'mail':
              $icon_name = 'envelope-o';
              break;

            case 'pdf':
              $icon_name = 'file-pdf-o';
              break;
          }

          // Build the icon.
          $path = '/' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOUR_THEME') . $path; //the path is relative to the theme 'YOUR_THEME'
          $icon = "<img src='" . $path . "' class='print-icon " . $link_class . "' alt='Print this page' />";

          // Show the icon with or without text, depending on config settings.
          switch ($show_link) {
            case 2:
              $text = $icon;
              break;
            case 3:
              $text = $icon . ' ' . $link_text;
              break;
          }
          $html = TRUE;
        }
        else {
          $text = $link_text;
          $html = FALSE;
        }

        return array(
          'text' => $text,
          'html' => $html,
          'attributes' => _print_ui_fill_attributes($link['description'], strip_tags($link_class), $new_window),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```